# How to remove Android Logo From Resource Folder

Tags: java, android

I've been developing a rather extensive game, and have finally arrived at the point where I can fix the last few problems, and touch it up a bit. I seem to have come across a rather abstract problem, however. Part of the program creates a deck of cards, the graphics for which are stored in my res folder. Also stored in this folder is the Android logo, which was set there by default. This wouldn't normally bother me, but the logo appears as one of the cards in my deck, holding the value of an ace. I tried to remove the logo from my resources, but my program will not run after doing so. I am completely stumped as to why this is. I have looked through all of my code, but nowhere is the logo called in to use. Does anyone have any ideas what I can do to fix this?

I have the feeling that this is where the problem occurs:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v("Blackjack", "On Create");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    m_player_bust = false;
    m_in_win = false;
    m_in_lose = false;
    m_hand_value = 0;
    m_dealer_value = 0;
    m_user_hand = new int[5];
    m_user_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    m_user_text.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    m_dealer_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    m_image = new ImageView[5];
    m_image[0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card_1);
    m_image[1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card_2);
    m_image[2] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card_3);
    m_image[3] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card_4);
    m_image[4] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card_5);
    m_dealer_image = new ImageView[5];
    m_dealer_image[0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dealer_card_1);
    m_dealer_image[1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dealer_card_2);
    m_dealer_image[2] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dealer_card_3);
    m_dealer_image[3] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dealer_card_4);
    m_dealer_image[4] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dealer_card_5);
    m_twist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twist);
    m_twist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dealCard();
        }
    });
    m_stick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stick);
    m_stick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dealerCards();
        }
    });
    final Button redeal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.redeal);
    redeal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            reDeal();
        }
    });
    m_num_dealt = 0;
    m_user_text.setText("[Player] 0");
    m_dealer_text.setText("[Dealer] 0");
    // reset the state of the buttons
    m_twist.setClickable(false);
    m_twist.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    m_stick.setClickable(false);
    m_stick.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    m_deck = new CardDeck();
    m_deck.CreateDeck();
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    } else {
        Log.v("Backjack", "ReCreate");
        LoadState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

public void reDeal() {
    if (m_deck.NeedShuffle()) {
        m_deck.Shuffle();
    }
    m_player_bust = false;
    m_num_dealt = 0;
    dealCard();
    dealCard();
    // reset the state of the buttons
    m_twist.setClickable(true);
    m_twist.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    m_stick.setClickable(true);
    m_stick.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    // reset the user text color
    m_user_text.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    m_dealer_text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    // reset other cards
    m_image[2].setImageResource(R.drawable.back_blue);
    m_image[3].setImageResource(R.drawable.back_blue);
    m_image[4].setImageResource(R.drawable.back_blue);
    // reset other cards
    m_dealer_image[0].setImageResource(R.drawable.back_blue);
    m_dealer_image[1].setImageResource(R.drawable.back_blue);
    m_dealer_image[2].setImageResource(R.drawable.back_blue);
    m_dealer_image[3].setImageResource(R.drawable.back_blue);
    m_dealer_image[4].setImageResource(R.drawable.back_blue);
    // clear dealer text
    m_dealer_text.setText("[Dealer] 0");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.v("Blackjack", "onPause() called");

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.v("Blackjack", "onStop() called");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v("Blackjack", "onDestroy() called");
}

public void dealCard() {
    int num_aces = 0;
    m_hand_value = 0;
    if (m_num_dealt < 5 && !m_player_bust) {
        // Get the next card
        m_user_hand[m_num_dealt] = m_deck.GetNextCard();
        m_image[m_num_dealt].setImageResource(m_deck
                .GetCardResource(m_user_hand[m_num_dealt]));
        m_num_dealt++;
        // calculate the value of the hand.
        for (int count = 0; count < m_num_dealt; count++) {
            if (m_deck.GetCardValue(m_user_hand[count]) == 11) {
                num_aces++;
            }
            m_hand_value += m_deck.GetCardValue(m_user_hand[count]);
        }
        // ACE adjust the value
        while (m_hand_value > 21 && num_aces > 0) {
            m_hand_value -= 10;
            num_aces--;
        }
        // Check for losery-ness.
        if (m_hand_value > 21) {
            // Loser :(
            m_twist.setClickable(false);
            m_twist.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            m_stick.setClickable(false);
            m_stick.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            m_user_text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            m_player_bust = true;
            ShowLose();
        }
        String output = "[Player] " + m_hand_value.toString();
        m_user_text.setText(output);
    }
}

public void dealerCards() {
    int card;
    int num_aces = 0;
    int dealer_cards = 0;
    m_dealer_value = 0;
    m_dealer_text.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    m_twist.setClickable(false);
    m_twist.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    m_stick.setClickable(false);
    m_stick.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    while (m_dealer_value <= m_hand_value && dealer_cards < 5) {
        card = m_deck.GetNextCard();
        m_dealer_image[dealer_cards].setImageResource(m_deck
                .GetCardResource(card));
        dealer_cards++;
        if (m_deck.GetCardValue(card) == 11) {
            num_aces++;
        }
        // calculate the value of the dealers cards
        m_dealer_value += m_deck.GetCardValue(card);
        while (m_dealer_value > 21 && num_aces > 0) {
            m_dealer_value -= 10;
            num_aces--;
        }
        // display result
        String output = "[Dealer] " + m_dealer_value.toString();
        m_dealer_text.setText(output);
    }
    if (m_dealer_value > m_hand_value && m_dealer_value <= 21) {
        ShowLose();
    } else {
        if (m_dealer_value > 21) {
            m_dealer_text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
        ShowWin();
    }
}

void ShowLose() {
    m_in_lose = true;
    m_user_text.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
    m_lose = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Loser!!!")
            .setMessage("You were trounced by the dealer :)")
            .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    m_in_lose = false;
                }
            }).show();
}

void ShowWin() {
    m_in_win = true;
    m_win = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Winner!!")
            .setMessage("You beat the dealer!")
            .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    m_in_win = false;
                }
            }).show();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    state.putInt("dealer_value", m_dealer_value);
    state.putInt("player_value", m_hand_value);
    state.putInt("num_cards", m_num_dealt);
    state.putBoolean("bust", m_player_bust);
    state.putBoolean("lose", m_in_lose);
    state.putBoolean("win", m_in_win);
    if (m_in_win && m_win != null) {
        m_win.dismiss();
    }
    if (m_in_lose && m_lose != null) {
        m_lose.dismiss();
    }
    if (m_user_hand != null) {
        state.putIntArray("player_hand", m_user_hand);
    }
    m_deck.SaveState(state);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
}

public void LoadState(Bundle state) {
    m_dealer_value = state.getInt("dealer_value");
    m_hand_value = state.getInt("player_value");
    m_num_dealt = state.getInt("num_cards");
    m_player_bust = state.getBoolean("bust");
    m_in_lose = state.getBoolean("lose");
    m_in_win = state.getBoolean("win");
    m_user_hand = state.getIntArray("player_hand");
    m_deck.LoadState(state);
    // display the users cards.
    for (int count = 0; count < m_num_dealt; count++) {
        m_image[count].setImageResource(m_deck
                .GetCardResource(m_user_hand[count]));
    }
    // Set the text values
    m_user_text.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    String output = "[Player] " + m_hand_value.toString();
    m_user_text.setText(output);
    output = "[Dealer] " + m_dealer_value.toString();
    m_dealer_text.setText(output);
    if (m_in_win) {
        ShowWin();
    } else if (m_in_lose) {
        ShowLose();
    } else {
        // we are in a player mode
        m_twist.setClickable(true);
        m_twist.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        m_stick.setClickable(true);
        m_stick.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you run the program in USB-connected debug mode? Or does it fail to even build? What error message does it give, and where does the error occur?

Comment: I am running it through an AVD. I can open the program, but it immediately crashes. My logcat is not throwing any errors, either.

Comment: it doesnt run because you must be using that default launcher icon in your app, it must be throwing some log output if its crashing...

Comment: Check your AndroidManifest.xml: is there something like `<application
... android:icon="@drawable/standard_icon" ...>` that could be referencing the default launcher icon?

Comment: @LarsH yes, it seems that was the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy of LarsH, I was able to solve the problem. I had been referencing the Android logo in the Manifest.xml

Comment: Glad you were able to solve the problem. The Manifest (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) is a core piece of configuration for your app, and it will serve you well to be aware of it. There are a number of important things that can only be done in the manifest, not in your java code or resources.